# why doesn't ltrace show gets(), puts()

Tags: linux, ltrace

On Ubuntu Yakkety Yak: 4.8.0-59-generic, I can't get ltrace to work. I expect it to show me gets() and puts() but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
// program name: e.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char str[80];
    gets(str);
    puts(str);
}

$ gcc -g e.c -o e
$ ldd ./e
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcbabee000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f224050f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558fe2c2f000)
$ ltrace ./e
hello
hello
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

Comment: `gets` is obsolete and dangerous. Use `fgets`

Comment: By replacing `gets` with `fgets` and running `/usr/bin/ltrace ./e` it is working as expected on Debian/Sid.

Comment: Hmmm.  On Ubuntu 14.04 this works fine. :-(

Comment: basile - No worries. I'm not planning on selling my e.c program to the NSA. It's just a trivial example to show a problem. Same problem if I use fgets.

Comment: @jszakmeister -- confirmed also for me working on 14.04. Not sure if this is a 16.10 issue or something peculiar to my installation.

Comment: Also working on 16.04